# How to make a sharepoint list title show up as a default column value

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I am trying to take a calendar title and let it show up as a default column value when someone tries to add a new event. Is there a way to do this within SharePoint, if so how?

Thank you for all the help.

Lucky

Comment: Can you develop a custom feature and deploy it to the server?

Comment: Do you mean you want the title to be dynamic? Else I guess you can edit the columns and set a default value? BR

Answer (score 0):

**Quick solution >>** When you change title of calendar, set Default value of that column as well.

**Proper solution >>** Create an event receiver for calendar and in ItemAdding event set value of title... should be like  item["Title"] = item.ParentList.Title